# How do you output a list of all man pages in a particular section?

Tags: shell, man

A man page for `fork`, for example, is in the System Calls section that has number 2:

`man 2 fork`

How do you see what else is section 2 without resorting to Google?

Comment: Without google, but via web, go to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_section_2.html (or main page here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/  )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This command lists the sorted names of all the entries in the given section:

```
man -aWS 1 \* | xargs basename | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' | sort -u
```

If you want to see the pathnames, use:

```
man -aWS 1 \* | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' | sort
```

This tells `man` to search a section for all commands using the wildcard pattern `*` (backslash-quoted so the shell doesn't interpret it). `-a` finds all matches, `-W` prints the pathnames instead of displaying the pages, and `-S 1` specifies section one. Change the `1` to whatever section you want to search.

The `sed` command strips the filename extensions; remove it if you want to see the complete filenames. `sort` sorts the results (`-u` removes duplicates).

For convenient reuse, this defines a Bash shell function:

```
function mansect { man -aWS ${1?man section not provided} \* | xargs basename | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' | sort -u; }
```

For example, you can invoke it as `mansect 3` to see the entries in section three.

[Tested on macOS.]

Comment: Nice - Thanks. I get some duplicates (e.g. paths in /Applications/Xcode.app and "Accelerate" in section 7), but nothing putting a `uniq` in the pipeline doesn't fix.

Comment: @xyz: I updated the sort command to `sort -u` to remove duplicates.

Comment: I get `No manual entry for *`

Answer (score 37):

To list all **installed** man pages from a specific section you can use [apropos](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=apropos&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en):

```
apropos -s 2 .  # use an regex for apropos . means anything
apropos -s 2 -w '*'  # use unix globbing for apropos
```

Comment: "apropos: -s: unknown option"

Comment: @MichaelMrozek what system are you using? It works for me, e.g: [output of apropos -s 2 -w '*'](http://nopaste.narf.at/show/1236/)

Comment: Thanks. The -s option is not present in Mac OS X apropos, which is presumably from BSD.

Comment: @f100 Ah ok, maybe try `man -a -s 2 '*'`

Comment: That seems more like it, but instead of listing them, it's actually invoking the viewer for each one in turn. I've hacked up a function to do listing which I posted in another comment. It likely has issues but it's enough for me :)

Comment: @xyz, please edit your question and add the Mac OSX tag to it so people will not take time trying parameters that do not belong to their Unices/Unix-Like systems. :)

Comment: FYI, `apropos -s 2 .` works great in Debian 8 (Jessie).

Answer (score 22):

Manpages are usually placed in `/usr/share/man`, but check `$MANPATH`, and are organized into sections like so:

```
 Section 1:
 /usr/share/man/man1/

 Section 2:
 /usr/share/man/man2/

 ...
```

So to list all installed section 2 manpages, do:

```
ls /usr/share/man/man2/
```

Or the more complete one:

```
find $(echo $MANPATH | tr ':' ' ') -path '*/man2/*'
```

The latter one will have problems if you have directories in `$MANPATH` with space in their names.

On most distributions you can also check available man pages with a package tool, e.g. on Debian derived distributions you can use `apt-file` like so:

```
apt-file search /man2/
```

Comment: Thanks - This was the start I needed. I made a shell function that is run e.g. `lman 2` and lists the unadorned name for each page on a new line and pages them. The function's body is: `find $(man --path | tr ':' ' ') -path "*/man$1/*"| xargs basename | sort | sed -E "s/\.$1(.gz)?\$//" | less`

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS X, the only thing I can get to work is `man -k . | grep -F '(3)'`, which lists everything in section 3.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, however the answers given here all didn't work for me. Therefore I came up with the following one-liner that works on **Ubuntu** 18.04 and **macOS** Mojave, 10.14.6:

```bsh
find $(man --path | tr ':' ' ') -type f -path '*man2*' \
  -exec basename {} \; | sed 's/\..*//' | sort
```

Quick run down:

- form Thors answer: `$(man --path | tr ':' ' ')` to get the current paths of the man pages
- `find <man paths> -type f -path '*man2*' -exec basename {} \;` gets the file names of all regular files in the man paths
- `sed` gets rid of the file extension
- `sort` alphabetically.

Comment: Works great on macOS 10.15.7 thanks @Ben

Comment: This listing is a bit too naive, it is great if it works for what you need to do — but keep in mind that the man search algorithm is pretty intricate. See `man man` for more details. (In particular, it can search for things 'near the roots', and all sectionN pages aren't under manN subfolders.)